# Array of structs with base struct returns wrong answer

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, return

My code was giving the wrong answer so I thinned it down to this.
When my variable arrayCounter=0, then it returns the correct answer in the array. 
But when arrayCounter=1, I get the incorrect answer of 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int x,y;
};

struct myStruct : base
{
  char c;
  int numOne;
}; myStruct MS[10]; //array of myStruct

base * returnArray(char c)  //function that returns array type
{
  if(c=='m'){ return MS;}
  //I plan to have other structs here similar to myStruct.
}

int main()
{
  MS[0].x=204;   //init 0 value in array
  MS[1].x=97;    //init 1 value in array

  int arrayCounter=0; //count through array. if=0, returns correctly. If=1, then not correct...
  cout<<returnArray('m')[arrayCounter].x<<endl; //MS[1].x=204, MS[1].x=0

  system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic, including indexing into an array, is static. It does not know the *dynamic type* of the objects you are accessing. As such, if you use a base pointer to an array of derived objects, and you try to increment this pointer, you are going to have a problem, because the pointer arithmetic assumes the object being pointed to really *is* a base object.

If you really want polymorphic behaviour with arrays, you'll have to use an *array of pointers*, and make the `returnArray` function return `base**`.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I tried it but it would not compile. does base ** return *MS, the pointer to myStruct?

Comment: Well, you'd have to declare `MS` as an array of pointers in order to use this approach

Comment: im ok with that method. so i made myStruct (*)MS[10]. and base(**) but i get an error. do you know why? thank you for your help btw. i have had this problem for a while.

Comment: `myStruct MS[10]` isn't an array of pointers. It's just an array of `myStruct` objects.

Comment: "invalid conversion from `myStruct**' to `base**'"  And 'x' has not been declared. all i did was make those two changes you suggested. weird error.

Comment: Oh yes, you have to declare `MS` to have type `base* [10]`. Also, you'll probably want to allocate the objects dynamically. You can't *just* make those two changes; you have to think about what you're doing.

Comment: yes good idea. It still says "x has not been declared", but I want to understand this so i will do some research on it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is sizeof(Base）= 8， when arrayCounter increase from 0 to 1 in returnArray('m')[arrayCounter], the address change is 8, but sizeof(myStruct) = 16, the address change 16 from MS[0] to MS[1],as the code shows

if you want this to happen, you can change the pointer type

`cout<<((myStruct*)returnArray('m'))[arrayCounter].x<<endl;`

the code list below outputs:

```
address of base* array index 0: 0x6013c0
address of base* array index 1: 0x6013c8
address of MS array index 0: 0x6013c0
address of MS array index 1: 0x6013d0
97

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct base
{
  int x,y;
};

struct myStruct : base
{
  char c;
  int numOne;
}; myStruct MS[10]; //array of myStruct

base * returnArray(char c)  //function that returns array type
{
  if(c=='m'){ return MS;}
  //I plan to have other structs here similar to myStruct.
}

int main()
{
  MS[0].x=204;   //init 0 value in array
  MS[1].x=97;    //init 1 value in array

  int arrayCounter=1; //count through array. if=0, returns correctly. If=1, then not correct...
  printf("address of base* array index 0: %p\n",&returnArray('m')[0]);
  printf("address of base* array index 1: %p\n",&returnArray('m')[1]);

  printf("address of MS array index 0: %p\n",&MS[0]);
  printf("address of MS array index 1: %p\n",&MS[1]);
  cout<<((myStruct*)returnArray('m'))[arrayCounter].x<<endl; //MS[1].x=204, MS[1].x=0

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your function `returnArray()` returns array of `base` while `operator []` actually calculates offset basing on element size smth like this:

```
template<typename T>
T& operator [](T* array, size_t index)
{
  *(array + sizeof(T) * index);
}
```

So when you pass an array of `base` this operator will calculate its size as `sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)`. Polymorphysm only works with pointers. So it'll go like this `myStruct* a[10]`
Or you can just return an array of myStruct: `myStruct* returnArray();`

And one more thing. If eventually you'll create a derived class that is even bigger than `myStruct` and try to store it in the array you'll succeed but the object you will store will be shrinked ti fit the size of `myStruct` and you will lose data.

Answer (score 0):

`myStruct* returnArray(char c)` will fix your current problem. But you will still be confused if you want to use many derived class in your codes.

The following codes might be a better choice:

```
struct Base
{
    int x,y;
    int get_x(){
        return x;
    }
}

cout << MS[arrayCounter].get_x() << endl;
```